# glmnet models comparison

Tags: glmnet

I'm trying to compare several GLMs realized using glmnet function. However, I do not understand which parameter I have to consider in order to define de best model which describe the relation among variables. For instance, in "normal" GLMs AIC or BIC values are generally used. Is there an enquivalent for glmnet models? Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think so, use cross-validation or a test set and get an accuracy measure, use this to compare your models.

Comment: user2974951 many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the *glmnet* package, the cross-validation is done via the ***cv.glmnet*** function call. In it, there is a $\lambda$ parameter that determines the effect of the penalty function $J(\beta)$,

$$ i.e., \hspace{3mm}  J(\beta) =\lambda \sum_{i} |\beta_i|$$

on the coefficients. This $\lambda$ parameter can be user-supplied, or if left NULL, the function call will run through a default set of values. In any case, this parameter is usually what is internally optimized by running a glmnet model through a sequence of a $\lambda$ values (i.e., $\mathbf{\lambda}=\{\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_k \}$ to find the optimal $\lambda^*$ based on cross-validation error.

Slide 19 here: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/datamining/lectures/18-val1.pdf

shows you visually how that $\lambda$ parameter search is done with the *glmnet* library and how they select the "optimal" $\lambda^*$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks! and sorry for the delay!